# Produce a duplicate-free version of the array

Tags: javascript

Produce a duplicate-free version of the array. Function should handle iterators that work with a sorted array. So I can do the first part, but don't understand how I would even approach using isSorted or iterator.

```
_.uniq = function(array, isSorted, iterator) {
  var unique = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var ele = array[i];

    if (unique.indexOf(ele) === -1) {
      unique.push(ele);
    }
  }

  return unique;
};
```

Comment: If the array is sorted, you just have to compare each element with the previous element, rather than searching for it in the result array.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterators that work with a sorted array"?

Comment: what is isSorted and iterator?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple & elegant way if you are happy to create a new array, unsorted and can ignore IE11.

```
  let fruits = ['pear','apple','banana','orange','apple','mango','banana','pear'];
  //https://www.codementor.io/tips/8243973127/how-to-remove-duplicates-within-a-javascript-array-using-es6-in-just-one-line
  //Array.from & new Set not supported in IE11, MDN has details.

let fruits_without_duplicates = Array.from(new Set(fruits));

console.log(fruits_without_duplicates); //["apple", "banana", "orange", "mango"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JavaScript [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the array, then get an array out of the set. Set holds unique values.

```
let fruits = ['pear','apple','banana','orange','apple','mango','banana','pear'];

let uniq_fruits = [... new Set(fruits)];

console.log(uniq_fruits); //[ 'pear', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango' ]
```